# ViewPager Fragment RecycleView Reset

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragmentpageradapter

I have 3 fragments in the `ViewPager`.

- PersonalFragment
- CropFragment
- NotesFragment

Every fragment has a `RecyclerView` and I was adding items using a dialog in it. However, when I go to the last fragment (i.e. `NoteFragment`), the first fragment's (i.e. `PersonalFragment`) `RecyclerView` gets empty (all items are removed). The same thing happens when I come back to the first fragment, the last fragment's `RecyclerView` resets (all items are removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to understand without seeing some of your code which is related. I think you might have implemented the `onResume` function incorrectly. Each time you go to the third fragment in your `ViewPager`, the first `Fragment` needs to be reinitialized and you need to take care of this in your `onResume` function.

However, another workaround for your problem is setting the off-screen page limit of the `ViewPager` like the following.

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Hope that helps.